# Syntax Error rendering ReactJS view

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

engine as an alternative to EJS in my node.js app. Anyway I used this example from here: https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views

```
var React = require('react');

var HelloMessage = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;
  }
});

module.exports = HelloMessage;
```

However I'm getting this error:[SyntaxError: D:\Data\ytko\elbp\views\index.jsx:5
    return ;
           ^
Unexpected token <];
Considering I copied this verbatim I'm slightly confused as to whats going on.

Thanks

Comment: Did you add it to your app? As in this step https://github.com/reactjs/express-react-views#add-it-to-your-app

Comment: Yes all the setup has been done

Comment: Could you provide the full error you're getting? My guess is that you're not translating JSX to JS.

Comment: Apologises I appear to have miscopied the error I'll edit my post now

Comment: I know it doesn't show it in the documentation. And I am not familiar with react.js. But this -> `return <div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>;` seems wrong.. I would expect something like `return "<div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>";`

Comment: That was my first instinct aswell and it returns the error that it has to be a DOM element you put in there as opposed to a string

Comment: Hmm, interesting. Anyways, maybe take a look at this.. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html

Comment: Also did you copy paste? Sometimes copy paste picks up hidden characters.

Comment: I've just retyped it to make sure it wasnt copy and paste, and that gotchas page isn't of us as it only applies if the actual HTML is rendering which mine isn't.

Comment: Try `render: function() {
    return (<div>Hello {this.props.name}</div>);
  }`

Comment: It seems that you didn't configure express properly and JSX is *not* converted to JS.